# Scala initialize empty stacks

Tags: scala

I have the following structure in Scala:

```
var pos = new HashMap[Char, Stack[Int]] withDefaultValue Stack[Int].empty
```

I am trying to initialize all the stacks to be empty.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Solution.scala:11: error: missing arguments for method apply in class GenericCompanion;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
        var pos = new HashMap[Char, Stack[Int]] withDefaultValue Stack[Int].empty
```

If I try removing the element type information:

```
var pos = new HashMap[Char, Stack[Int]] withDefaultValue Stack.empty
```

It also fails:

```
Solution.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Nothing]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int]
Note: Nothing <: Int, but class Stack is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Int`. (SLS 3.2.10)
        var pos = new HashMap[Char, Stack[Int]] withDefaultValue Stack.empty
```

I am using mutable collections:

```
import collection.mutable._
```

How can I initialize the stacks to be empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`empty` is a generic method on the companion `Stack` object so you need to supply it with type arguments, otherwise you receive a `Stack[Nothing]`.

Use `Stack.empty[Int]`:

```
var pos = new HashMap[Char, Stack[Int]] withDefaultValue Stack.empty[Int]
```